# display: table-cell causing image to overflow its parent div IE11 only

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm displaying images of A4, A5, Quarto etc sized products in a responsive grid and and using max-width: 70%; (and other percent values) am able to take arbitrarily sized images and display them in correct scale. This is working well in about 10 browser/OS combos - except Win 10/IE11

Good display:

[image]

Here each cell in the grid (`<div class="product">`) has a black outline and contains an image wrapper in red (`<div class='productimage'>`) plus other wrapper divs the the text and price. Using a [jquery solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440944/carousel-make-a-div-within-an-item-same-height-as-sibling-items-div) I have made all the grid cells the same height.

In IE11 the images seem to refuse to scale and want to render full size instead of a percent of their container's width:

[image]

Removing `display: table-cell;` from the `.productimage` class that wraps the image gives this on IE11:

[image]

So size is now correct again, but image is at top of the div. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934332/how-do-i-position-an-image-at-the-bottom-of-div) and similar solutions based on `position: relative` / `position: absolute` but cannot get it to work, as, I think, my divs do not have a fixed height, and/or height is set by jquery.

Codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENNvbZ

```js
function equalize() {
  var $maxImgHeight = 0;
  var $maxTxtHeight = 0;

  $('.productrow .productimage').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).height() > $maxImgHeight) {
      $maxImgHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  $(".productrow .productimage").height($maxImgHeight);

  $('.productrow .producttitle').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).height() > $maxTxtHeight) {
      $maxTxtHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  $(".productrow .producttitle").height($maxTxtHeight);


  displayWindowSize();
}

function equalizeOnResize() {
  $(".productrow .productimage").height('auto');
  $(".productrow .producttitle").height('auto');
  equalize();
}

window.onresize = equalizeOnResize;
window.onload = equalize;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
body {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0px;
}
.centered_content {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}
/* 
      scale images to relative paper sizes
    */

.a4_diary_image {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.quarto_diary_image {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.a5_diary_image {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.a6_diary_image {
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.pocket_diary_image {
  max-width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
/* 
      responsive grid for product categories - show 1,2,3 or 4 products 
      per row depending on screen size. first .product is mobile - rest 
      need to have a clear inserted into start of each new row so boxes line up evenly
    */

.product {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  .product {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .product:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  .product {
    width: 33.3%;
  }
  .product:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .product {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .product:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
/* 
      detailied styling of each .product 
    */

.producttitle {
  padding: 4px;
}
/* 
       display: table-cell; seems to be causing IE problem, when removed
       the image are displayed at the correct size and within the DIVs, but 
       not aligned to the bottom
    */

.productimage {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 100%;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
}
.product_todetails {
  outline: 0px solid black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000080;
}
.productprice {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #000080;
}
.productmoredetails {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.productmoredetails .btn-primary {
  background-color: #444;
  border: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">

  <div class="productrow">
    <!--  nth-child wrapper -->

    <div class="product">
      <div class='productimage'>
        <a href='a4ultra_detail.php'>
          <img class='a4_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/A4_test.gif'>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class='producttitle'>
        <a href='a4ultra_detail.php'>A4  </a> 
      </div>

      <div class='product_todetails'>
        <div class='productprice'>
          &euro;10.00
        </div>
        <div class='productmoredetails'>
          <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="product">
      <div class='productimage'>
        <a href='#'>
          <img class='a6_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/A6_test.gif'>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class='producttitle'>
        <a href='#'>A6 - this can go onto several lines and the other DIVs will line up</a> 
      </div>

      <div class='product_todetails'>
        <div class='productprice'>
          &euro;10.00
        </div>
        <div class='productmoredetails'>
          <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="product">
      <div class='productimage'>
        <a href='#'>
          <img class='a5_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/A5_test.gif'>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class='producttitle'>
        <a href='#'>A5</a> 
      </div>

      <div class='product_todetails'>
        <div class='productprice'>
          &euro;10.00
        </div>
        <div class='productmoredetails'>
          <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="product">
      <div class='productimage'>
        <a href='#'>
          <img class='quarto_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/Q_test.gif'>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class='producttitle'>
        <a href='#'>Quarto</a> 
      </div>

      <div class='product_todetails'>
        <div class='productprice'>
          &euro;10.00
        </div>
        <div class='productmoredetails'>
          <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="product">
      <div class='productimage'>
        <a href='#'>
          <img class='pocket_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/POCKET_test.gif'>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class='producttitle'>
        <a href='#'>Pocket</a> 
      </div>

      <div class='product_todetails'>
        <div class='productprice'>
          &euro;10.00
        </div>
        <div class='productmoredetails'>
          <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>
  <!-- / nth-child wrapper -->


</div>
<!-- / panel-body -->
</div>
<!-- / panel -->
```

Comment: i suspect its the height 100% on .productimage, probably need to add a width and height in pixels

Comment: hi, it's a responsive site so setting pixels is not an option. Unless I'm mistaken, the image should not be bigger than its container div. for the A4 it should be 100% high and thus 100% wide, but that 100% wide is of approx (excluding ) 1/4 of 1,100 pixels on a PC - this should limit the height.

Comment: I just tried setting my 100% images to 70% on the code pen, no fix

Comment: May I ask why you use `display: table-cell`?

Comment: For the vertical-align: bottom; - could not get image down any other way

Comment: Posted an answer, let me know if it is an option using `flexbox`

Comment: If you want to use display: table-cell; just make sure to make the parent have display: table-row; and grand parent display: table; to get best cross-browser results

Comment: @evilReiko - just reied that, no success, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` instead. More suitable for layout than `display: table/table-cell`

*Note, you need to add prefixed flexbox property for amongst other IE10*

Updated/Added CSS rules

```
.productimage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  outline : 1px dashed red;
}
.productimage a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Sample snippet

```js
function equalize(){
  var $maxImgHeight =0;
  var $maxTxtHeight =0;
  
  $('.productrow .productimage').each(function(i){
    if ($(this).height() > $maxImgHeight) { 
      $maxImgHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  $(".productrow .productimage").height($maxImgHeight);

  $('.productrow .producttitle').each(function(i){
    if ($(this).height() > $maxTxtHeight) { 
      $maxTxtHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  $(".productrow .producttitle").height($maxTxtHeight);


  //displayWindowSize();
}



function equalizeOnResize (){
  $(".productrow .productimage").height('auto');
  $(".productrow .producttitle").height('auto');
  equalize();
}



window.onresize = equalizeOnResize;
window.onload = equalize;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}
body {
  color: #444444;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin:0px;
}
.centered_content {
  max-width:1100px; 
  margin: auto;
}

/* 
  scale images to relative paper sizes
*/
.a4_diary_image {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.quarto_diary_image {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.a5_diary_image {
  max-width: 70%;
}
.a6_diary_image {
  max-width: 50%;
}
.pocket_diary_image {
  max-width: 40%;
}

/* 
  responsive grid for product categories - show 1,2,3 or 4 products 
  per row depending on screen size. first .product is mobile - rest 
  need to have a clear inserted into start of each new row so boxes line up evenly
*/

.product {
  background-color: white; 
  padding:10px 20px ;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;  
  outline: 1px dashed black;  
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 799px) {
  .product {width: 50%;}
  .product:nth-child(2n+1){
      clear:left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 999px){
  .product {width: 33.3%;}
  .product:nth-child(3n+1){
      clear:left;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .product {width: 25%;}
  .product:nth-child(4n+1){
    clear:left;
  }
}


/* 
  detailied styling of each .product 
*/

.producttitle {
  padding:4px;
}


/*   ***************************************
     used flexbox here instead of table-cell
*/
.productimage {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  outline : 1px dashed red;
}
.productimage a {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-top: auto;
}
/*   ***************************************
*/


.product_todetails {
  outline: 0px solid black;  
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  padding:4px;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000080;
}

.productprice {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #000080;
}


.productmoredetails {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.productmoredetails .btn-primary {background-color: #444;border:black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default ">
  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="productrow">
      <!--  nth-child wrapper -->


      <div class="product">
        <div class='productimage'>
          <a href='a4ultra_detail.php'>
            <img class='a4_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/A4_test.gif'>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class='producttitle'>
          <a href='a4ultra_detail.php'>A4  </a> 
        </div>

        <div class='product_todetails'>
          <div class='productprice'>
            &euro;10.00
          </div>
          <div class='productmoredetails'>
            <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="product">
        <div class='productimage'>
          <a href='#'>
            <img class='a6_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/A6_test.gif'>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class='producttitle'>
          <a href='#'>A6 - this can go onto several lines and the other DIVs will line up</a> 
        </div>

        <div class='product_todetails'>
          <div class='productprice'>
            &euro;10.00
          </div>
          <div class='productmoredetails'>
            <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="product">
        <div class='productimage'>
          <a href='#'>
            <img class='a5_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/A5_test.gif'>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class='producttitle'>
          <a href='#'>A5</a> 
        </div>

        <div class='product_todetails'>
          <div class='productprice'>
            &euro;10.00
          </div>
          <div class='productmoredetails'>
            <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="product">
        <div class='productimage'>
          <a href='#'>
            <img class='quarto_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/Q_test.gif'>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class='producttitle'>
          <a href='#'>Quarto</a> 
        </div>

        <div class='product_todetails'>
          <div class='productprice'>
            &euro;10.00
          </div>
          <div class='productmoredetails'>
            <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="product">
        <div class='productimage'>
          <a href='#'>
            <img class='pocket_diary_image' src='http://solomon.ie/so/POCKET_test.gif'>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class='producttitle'>
          <a href='#'>Pocket</a> 
        </div>

        <div class='product_todetails'>
          <div class='productprice'>
            &euro;10.00
          </div>
          <div class='productmoredetails'>
            <a href='#' class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">More info / buy</a>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>
    <!-- / nth-child wrapper -->


  </div>
  <!-- / panel-body -->
</div>
<!-- / panel -->
```

Comment: flexbox is problamtic even in modern browsers

Comment: @evilReiko Not when used properly

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your answer. It has fixed the IE 11 issue and also still works on Edge and Chrome/FF/Safari on PC and Mac, plus iPhone/Ipad and Android tablet. But, now Andriod Browser 4.2 is broken, image are at top of div. MDN says flex is supported from 4.4, canIuse says there is support for the 'old' flexbox from 4.1 - any workarounds? I've accepted your answer as it did fix the IE issue.

Comment: By prefixes, is this correct?.productimage {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  -webkit-box-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flexbox-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  outline : 1px dashed blue;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

Comment: @KevInSol Don't own a that old Android so can't really say, though here is a link, and let me know if it helped: https://benfrain.com/flexbox-gotchas-for-android-2-1-4-3-stock-browser/

Answer (score 0):

Tables are so problematic. The cells are forced to be at least as big as the contents, but if you use percentages in the contents then it's a circular definition.

So CSS2.1 left lots of these things as undefined behavior, and therefore browsers behave differently. Now CSS Tables Module 3 is attempting to fix this but it's not stable yet.

What usually works for me is:

- Position the cells relatively
- Position the contents absolutely
- Use `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` to size and place the contents as desired inside the cell.

Comment: Correction: tables are not problematic, that's how they work. You can add table-layout: fixed; for the table and then the cells will render differently (all cells get equal width/height if no width/height specified.)

Comment: @evilReiko The CSS2.1 automatic model is a joke. But the whole Tables section is a mess. And there is not much interoperability among implementations except in the most basic cases.

Comment: I think I mentioned I already tried that and linked to another SO post on that